# Nimber $2^{2^k} - 1$ is a multiplicative generator of $[2^{2^k}]$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

Let $t = 2^{2^k}$, and consider the field $[t]$ of [nimbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimber) below $t$. For $k \leq 6$ one can check that $t - 1$ (in the usual arithmetic sense) is a multiplicative generator of $[t] \backslash \{0\}$. Is this true in general?

Comment: Nice observation! I've successfully tested it for $k\leq 12$. On the other hand, this may still be just by a chance since roughly half of the elements are generators. Testing for larger $k$ cannot be accomplished since that involves Fermat numbers with incompletely known factorizations.